# Ubuntu 14.04 usb keyboard shift not working

Tags: usb, keyboard

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Yesterday my <kbd>shift</kbd> key on my usb keyboard stopped working. The laptop <kbd>shift</kbd> key works fine. 
I have tried the following things to fix the issue but nothing works.

1. restart laptop.
2. tried other usb keyboard.
3. moved usb to another port.
4. tested usb keyboard on other machines and it works fine.

Can anyone give me something else to try.

Comment: Try going into all settings > keyboard, click on shortcuts tab, go to custom shortcuts and create a new shortcut, click where it says 'New Accelerator' then press the shift in question

Comment: There is no New Accelerator

Comment: To the right of the shortcut created, sorry that should have been Disabled > New Accelerator

Comment: under settings> keyboard > custom shortcuts all I am getting is a input box that says name and command

Comment: Ok. Full Step by step: Go into all settings > keyboard, click on shortcuts tab, go to custom shortcuts and create a new shortcut with the '+' sign. Enter name and command (any name, and any command are fine). Click where it says Disabled. This will change to 'New Accelerator', and if you press a button/combination of buttons it will change to those buttons. Press the shift in question. See if it detects that.

Comment: hi thanks for the step by step.when i press the shift button it goes straight back to disabled

Comment: If it is doing that it means your keystroke is going through, but it doesn't seem like it's mapped though. Not sure what to do next yet.

Comment: Guys, why `Shift+Ctrl L` and `Ctrl+Shift L` are different hotkeys? Is it a new 14.04 feature? How can I disable it?